# what edition of SQ Server Express is available at amazon for free tier

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, full-text-search

what edition of sql server express is available at amazon AWS for free?
They say that:

> The Amazon RDS free tier applies to Amazon RDS for MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle (under the Bring-Your-Own-License licensing model) and SQL Server (running SQL Server Express Edition).

I need Microsoft SQL server with **full-text search**, and this is (available from MS):

> SQL Server Express with Advanced Services.
>   Experience the full feature set of SQL Server Express. This package contains the database engine, Express Tools, Reporting Services, Full Text Search, management tools, and all the components of SQL Server Express. This package is a larger size and will take longer to download.

There are also other versions, like LocalDB and...

So, the question is - what version is at Amazon Web Services Free Tier?

Comment: So Microsoft is saying SQL Server Express has full text search and Amazon RDS Free Tier says it runs on Express. Hence the logical conclusion is Amazon RDS Free Tier supports full text search. Of course, since it's free, you can just try it out and see what's included for real.

Comment: @ZoffDino, :) yes, but the question is what edition of SQL express is on AWS for free. Yes, I can just try out, but then every one else would have to. However, this way, all will know without trying.